# Django Exception Type: KeyError Exception Value

Tags: python, django, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy tratando de crear un formulario para la creación de un post y me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
KeyError at /pagina_crear/
'autor'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/pagina_crear/
Django Version: 4.1.3
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'autor'
Exception Location: E:\ProyectoFinal\EntregaFinal\Blog\views.py, line 31, in pagina_crear
Raised during:  Blog.views.pagina_crear
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Edu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.0
Python Path:    
['E:\\ProyectoFinal\\EntregaFinal',
 'C:\\Users\\Edu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Edu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Edu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Edu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\Edu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 10 Jan 2023 19:55:50 +0000
```

```
class Pagina(models.Model):
    titulo=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subtitulo=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fecha_posteo=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    autor= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    imagen=models.ImageField(upload_to="post", null=True, blank=True)
    cuerpo=RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

    #cuerpo=models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.titulo} - {self.autor}"

class paginaform(forms.Form):
    titulo=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    subtitulo=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    #autor=forms.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    imagen=forms.ImageField(label="Imagen")
    cuerpo=forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())

    def pagina_crear(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        formulario= paginaform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            informacion=formulario.cleaned_data
            titulo= informacion["titulo"]
            subtitulo= informacion["subtitulo"]
            #fecha_posteo= informacion["fecha_posteo"]
            autor= informacion["autor"]
            imagen= informacion["imagen"]
            cuerpo= informacion["cuerpo"]
            pagina= Pagina(titulo=titulo, subtitulo=subtitulo, autor=autor, imagen=imagen, cuero=cuerpo)
            pagina.save()
            paginas=Pagina.objects.all()
            return render(request, "pagina_detalle.html", {"paginas":paginas})

        #else:
            return render (request, "librosform.html", {"form": formulario, "mensaje": "Informacion no valida"})
    
    else:
        formulario= paginaform()
        return render (request, "pagina_form.html", {"form": formulario})
```

Comment: Hola, creo que debería revisar la indentación. Quizá solo quedo mal pegado el código en la pregunta. Si lo tenes tal cual fíjate que esta ´pagina_crear ´ y la linea de abajo con el ´if´ sin indentar.

Comment: Hola, si perdón, copie mal el código, soy muy newee, segun yo, no hay problemas de indentación

Answer (score 0):

Voy a asumir que en tu template de Django usas el {{form.as_table}} o algo similar, lo que sucede es que cuando se hace el renderizado (no recuerdo si se dice así) del formulario te muestra los campos del titulo, subtitulo, imagen, cuerpo, pero el campo de autor lo tienes comentado, por lo cual este es el único campo que no se mostraría, pero en tu código, justo debajo de:

```
#fecha_posteo= informacion["fecha_posteo"]
```

tienes:

```
autor= informacion["autor"]
```

Entonces, cada que haces un post, en el request.POST, vendría la información del titulo, subtitulo, imagen y cuerpo, pero nunca un valor para autor. Recuerda que es como un diccionario, entonces llega algo así:

```
{'titlo':'Escrito en el agua', 'subitulo': 'No confies', 'imagen':'logo.png', 'cuerpo':'lorem ipsum....'}
```

por lo cual, cuando tratas de traer el valor que tiene el key 'autor' te dice que este no existe, ya que nunca se envió.

Para resolverlo, lo que puedes hacer es también comentar la línea o la otra es hacer un "**.get()**"
Ejemplo:

```
autor = información.get("autor", '')
```

El código anterior te devolver un string vacío, pero al menos no te dará error.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

introducir el código aquí